# Laravel 8.x Session Storage Issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've followed a guide on a simple referral system for user registrations, at first it was working and the session was being passed to the overridden registered method. But now it's randomly stopped working and to my knowledge after some dd statements placed in the registered method and where the session key was being set, it's returning null as if the session variable has dissolved. Here's my code:

RegisterController.php

```
    public function showRegistrationForm(Request $request) {
        if ($request->has('ref')) {
            session(['referrer' => $request->query('ref')]);
        }

        return view('auth.register');
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $referrer = User::whereUsername(session()->pull('referrer'))->first();

        dd($referrer);

        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'ip' => request()->ip(),
            'role' => 'user',
            'referrer_id' => $referrer ? $referrer->id : null,
        ]);
    }

    protected function registered(Request $request, $user) {
        if ($user->referrer !== null) {
            $user->referrer->notify(new ReferralBonus($user->referrer, $user));
        }

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

In the create method, the dd is returning **null** but when I dd under the showRegistrationForm it's pulling the value correctly. I've tried a few workarounds like adding the StartSession class to middleware group and no luck with that. In my **register.blade.php** I'm also pulling the session value to tell the user they are signing up with a referral and the value is displaying there correctly as well.

Comment: You are `dd`ing the response of a Model, not the `session` itself, so can you `dd(session('referrer'))` ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti It's also returning null just like the response from the model, and i dd'd the model response because it should return an array of the user class if it was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have added code somewhere that is not allowing the session to be saved. Any early termination of the process [e.g., `dd($anything)`], including within the View, will prevent the session from being saved.

Try adding an explicit `session()->save()` after setting the referrer. This will force an early save and should serve to confirm or reject the statements above.

```php
if ($request->has('ref')) {
    session(['referrer' => $request->query('ref')]);
    session()->save();
}
```

A quick additional edit:

> In the create method, the dd is returning null but when I dd under the showRegistrationForm it's pulling the value correctly.

It may be important to note that you can access variables you have just set to the session, even if they have not technically been saved. This may provide a false impression as to what is happening.

Comment: I should have included in my original post that I've tried an explicit save of the session but had no luck, I just tried again without any dd's and still not working, I added the DD again in the create function and it's still returning null.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what's happening. Either way, the issue does not appear to be in the code you have shared. Perhaps if you provide more code, the issue will present itself.

Comment: Additionally, you are aware that `session()->pull()` deletes the value from the session upon retrieval? Just want to make sure you aren't using that somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, I just had fixed it and was coming here to reply and say my thanks for trying to help in anyway, It was ultimately the code I had in my view to display which referrer code you were using -- Which was using the pull method, those pesky mistakes always get you.

Comment: Always use `session('referrer')` when you want to fetch, mostly everything (in Laravel) follows this standard, so if you want to get the value and remove it you will need to use `->pull('...')` or similar. If you follow this rule, you will not get this problem again with anything else (mostly).